# Problema ao trocar imagem com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom é assim, eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownPress, false);
    var valoresDigitados = [];

    function keyDownPress(e) {
      var keyCode = e.keyCode;
      valoresDigitados.push(String.fromCharCode(keyCode));
    }
    setInterval(function(){
    var codigos = valoresDigitados.join("");


    $.getJSON('pclock.php?codigo='+codigos, function(arrayinfo) {

    if(arrayinfo[0] != ""){

        console.log(arrayinfo[0]);
        var foto = arrayinfo[0];
    $("#foto").attr("src", foto); 

    }
    });

    }, 3000);
    </script>
```

A variável foto é extraida através de um documento php, no qual o ajax faz a requisição para saber o valor, que por norma o valor retornado é "0.jpg", contudo o meu script não está a trocar a foto da minha página pela foto "0.jpg".

Qual seria o problema?

Comment: voce verificou se *arrayinfo[0]*, se está vindo "0.jpg" mesmo?

Comment: Sim está, eu imprimi pelo console.log e ele mostrou

Comment: eu fiz um teste aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljc9yxs8/
e o trecho que voce tem que muda está ok, pode ser interferencia da parte de fora deste trecho. Viu se no console está estourando erro, travando o resto do codigo?

Comment: Já consegui, era um erro mesmo no codigo anterior, obrigado pela ajuda!